What should we do about the [hello-world] tag?
Recently I came across a question with a hello-world tag, which was asked a few days ago. (I can't post the link of it because it is now deleted)
After searching on Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow, I obtained the following information:

There are three questions under that tag (excluding the deleted one mentioned at the beginning):

Why am I not able to open my "hello world" document that I saved in notepad on python? [duplicate]
A simple program for printing in Java, but I do not know what the problem is with printing [duplicate]
How to I multiply two small matrices, with a Gaudi accelerator?


All the questions are about printing "hello world" or program of that level. And two of them are downvoted and duplicate.
In this question, the tag seems to be decided to be burninated. But now there are still questions under it asked within two months.

It seems not to add adds anything valuable to the question, but only the knowledge level of the asker (or the question).
So, what should we do with it? Burninate it again? Leave it there? Or something else?
Related: ghost question in hello-world tag

We should greet is just as politely, of course. Are we not civilized beings?

There is a reason why the entire privilege system of Stack Overflow does little more than open up more janitorial duties to you - the whole site is a constant loop of cleaning up after people. Tags are no different. The hello world tag is a symptom of a problem. Which exact problem I keep changing my opinion about. Currently I have landed on Stack Overflow looking a whole lot like other websites (Reddit, Twitter) while not making any effort at all to distinguish itself from those other websites. Hence, people tag like they would a Twitter post. It's what is in their DNA now.

I have removed the tag from those 3 questions. If those edits don't get rolled back or a new question gets tagged again the tag will be gone at 03:00 UTC.
